# Understanding Netconf and Yang in NMS

Tags: model, schema, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf

I am really new to Network management systems where object modelling, netconf and Yang being used widely.

I would like to know if there is any list of books or articles to follow to understand the whole concept. Any opensource projects in C and python for handson experience with the same would be of great help.

Comment: I referenced a couple of documents in one of my recent [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34651529/878469) which you might find useful. See RFC6244 in particular.

Comment: I found documentation for NETCONF/Yang in http://www.netconfcentral.org/ quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading Confd-basic from tail-f. It has lots of documentation, tutorials and it is a top-tied config management framework. https://developer.cisco.com/site/confD/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

There is a book due to be published by Addison Wesley on May 10, 2019:

Network Programmability with YANG: Data Modeling-driven Management with YANG.

by Benoit Claise, Joe Clarke and Jan Lindblad.

According to the preview book cover it will cover the structure of network automation with YANG, NETCONF, RESTCONF and friends.

In terms of open source software, the `yuma123` and `netopeer2` projects both have NETCONF Client and Server implementations written in C.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following books.

1. Network Programmability with YANG: The Structure of Network
   Automation with YANG, NETCONF, RESTCONF, and gNMI by Benoit Claise,
   Joe Clarke and Jan Lindblad
2. SDN_ Software Defined Networks_ An Authoritative Review of Network
   Programmability Technologies by by Thomas D. Nadeau, Ken Gray

Articles:

1. Google for "Yang based network automation"
2. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/netconfyang-network-automation-over-snmp-sahan-hannadige/